# delete a standard account and log with the admin account

Tags: mac, password, user-account

I have an old Mac with one (admin) account. The mac can boot without any problem, but I don't remember the admin password. A friend of mine had the 'brilliant' idea to create a new (non-admin) user and set it to load by default.

Can I access the admin's documents with this new account and afterwards just delete the freshly created account?
Or is there a way to changer/recover the admin password?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/inherited-mac-mini-dont-have-admin-info

Comment: Also, is "standard" an admin account?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following Apple KB on resetting the Administrator password:  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1274