# Creating New Administrator Account

Tags: macos, administrator

So I am following [How can I get admin access to a Mac without knowing the current password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/how-can-i-get-admin-access-to-a-mac-without-knowing-the-current-password?rq=1) to create a new administrator account.

I entered the command `rm /db/.AppleSetupDone`. and the computer prompts me with the following:

```
override -w---r-- /root/wheel /var/db/.AppleSetupDone?
```

(It says something like that) I type in: `yes` and then it says “read only file system”. After I reboot nothing happens, I don’t have to create a new account or do anything like that.

I suspect it is because the file system is “read-only”; is there any way around that?

Comment: You did type in the command  **mount -uw /** before you typed the **rm /db/.AppleSetupDone**, yes?

Comment: Yes, I did type in that command

Comment: The 'w' part of the **mount -uw** command should mount the disk read/write. Would you please edit your post to include the version of OS X on this Mac, please?

Comment: `/var/` is only a link to `/private/var` - does the same thing happen if you try to delete `/private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone`?

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? Are you trying to bypass account restrictions set by an administrator, for example? There is a very simple way of doing this but the question of why you're restricted to a non-administrator account has to be asked...