# How do I find out my Mac OSx admin password without changing it?

Tags: macos, mac, administrator

Please help me as I do not want to reset the password. I inherited this mac and I do not know the admin password but i aslo dont want to change it

Comment: If it were that easy, it would be pointless

Comment: Yes, I believe you are missing the point of password security on a computer. I think you will have to wipe the computer and start clean.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/how-can-i-get-admin-access-to-a-mac-without-knowing-the-current-password?rq=1 for methods to reset an unknown administrator password.

Answer (score 3):

OS X does not store a plain-text copy of your administrator password. This makes it impossible to have the computer show you the existing password.

OS X can only test if an attempted password is the administrator password.

OS X has no way to show you the original. The original is immediately thrown away when the password is set; only a hash of the password is kept.

## Why? Hashed Passwords

Passwords are stored as [mathematically derived hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of the original. This hash makes it possible to determine if an attempted password matches the real password, but it also makes it impossible to determine the real password.

Answer (score 0):

Unless its linked to iCloud, in which case you would be able to reset it as if you'd reset your Apple ID password (not recover it), I believe there is **no way** of being able to do such thing. Not even change it.

Comment: "Not even change it"... You can change the password without having the password, it just requires being technically inclined and knowing your way around the Mac and the Terminal, as well as restarting a bit, and it isn't always doable, such as if FileVault is enabled.