# Second login screen has me locked out

Tags: macos, password, filevault, login

I am locked out of my MacBook Pro. When I turn it on, I get the usual login screen which shows my username and asks for my password. I type in my password and at first, all seems right in the world--there is a progress bar as if it were logging in. But then a second login screen comes up asking me to type in both my username and my password. I cannot get past this screen. Very confused and a little distressed. I am running macOS Sierra on a late-2013 15" MacBook Pro. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you enable FileVault (disk encryption)?

Comment: I did enable FileVault, yes.

Comment: @misterjoff did you ever fix this? Have the same issue now

Answer (score 1):

I have just encountered this issue. The way that worked for me is to create a new administrator as described in [How can I get admin access to a Mac without knowing the current password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/how-can-i-get-admin-access-to-a-mac-without-knowing-the-current-password), then use the new administrator to reset the original accounts password. Then I was able to log into the original account.

Before this method, I have tried

- resetting pram and smc
- running disk check from recovery mode
- unsuccessfully trying to modify the encrypted apfs to decrypt it (it seems like encrypted is default)
- resetting password of my original accounts from recovery mode
- changing the password to the login keychain in terminal in recovery mode in case my password on the keychain wasn't updated along with the reset password in recovery mode

I am running Mac OS High Sierra