# Forgot Password After Amnesia

Tags: imac, password

I need to connect my 2012 iMac back to the internet. I had it shipped back to my parent's house (completely different state from where I had it) after I had a motor vehicle accident while working for my dad.

I did have a password to log into it, but I forgot it because of the amnesia I had after being hit. I need to connect it in Recovery mode to use the reset password tool so it can successfully change the code. Right now it says "There was an error connecting to the Apple ID server."

Comment: Is there Ethernet available so that in recovery mode you can open safari and navigate to the internet? I’m guessing you don’t want to make a new admin account and just choose a password so you can get on the internet and then reset the password of the main account? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/how-can-i-get-admin-access-to-a-mac-without-knowing-the-current-password

Answer (score 1):

If the machine has an Internet connection, worst case you can use iCloud.com —> Find my iPhone, which will also show your Mac. You can put it in Lost Mode, which will wipe the drive, but let you log in with your iCloud password. You need a backup though since this will zap all the files on the machine.