# I have a password problem with my iMac OSX 2007 desktop

Tags: imac, password, snow-leopard

I just recently bought a iMac OSX 2007 desktop from someone online. She does not have the password. It is password protected and I’ve been trying to figure out how to do a factory reset to reset the password without needing the password to get into it, nothing is working.

A friend gave me their Snow Leopard Mac OSX disk to try that and it still won't do anything. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Is the login screen a regular login screen (where there's a place for the password, and buttons for "Sleep," "Restart," and "Shut down," and often a visual background, or is it instead a Firmware Password login screen (where there's only a black-and-white drawing of a lock and a window in which to enter the password, and there's no background) ?

Comment: Re the above comment - if you do get a regular login screen, rather than the black & white one, then before next reboot insert the Snow Leo CD, restart & hold the C key when you hear the chimes, until you see a desktop. You can wipe & install from there if there's no firmware lock.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica the first one you mentioned

Comment: @Tetsujin i did try that and im not sure if something is wrong with the disk reader but its still not working. Everything ive tried it just keeps going right back to the password screen

Comment: Try booting into [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/12.0/mac/12.0)

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/how-can-i-get-admin-access-to-a-mac-without-knowing-the-current-password